# how to customize camera screen with UIImagepickercontroller

Tags: iphone

i want to display camera as a mirror but not capture the photo or to shoot video .
so i need to display camera with only cancel button.
please anybody help me thanx in adv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use cameraOverlayView property to use your own control instead of default control.

Please see http://blog.blackwhale.at/2009/10/custom-video-overlay-view-on-the-iphone/